# Monster Debugger BreakPoints no working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, debugging

I'm new to flash development and have decided to start by trialing various pieces of development software; I'm developing on a mac.

Currently I'm using TextMate with [Simon Gregory's ActionScript 3 Bundles](https://github.com/simongregory/actionscript3-tmbundle) and the [Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/).  I have also installed the Flex SDK (used by the bundles to compile the code I believe) and a debug version of the flash player.

I've added the following code (and the required import) to my main class constructor:

```
        MonsterDebugger.initialize(this);
        MonsterDebugger.trace(this, "Hello World!");
        MonsterDebugger.breakpoint(this);
```

The code compiles and runs fine.  The debugger connects and displays the hello world message but the debugger will not stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: I'm using TextMate to edit the code but like i said it seems to compile and run fine...  Although, I did think that maybe the fact that TextMate is piping the code to the flex compiler might be part of the problem, maybe it does something slightly differently to the standard flash compiler...

Answer (score 0):

When you compile using flash,flex or any of the generic IDEs There is a connection made from the IDE to the debug version of flash player.
Break points will only trigger in the editor in conjunction with that connection to the player.
I have never used TextMate but I doubt it has this capability.

If you want a free version of an IDE look into [flashdevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) I am pretty sure it supports debugging.
Sorry, I don't ever use the free versions I always use licensed adobe software and FlashDevelop is the only free IDE I am aware of.


Also, if I can make a suggestion don't use third party libraries when you are learning a language.
This promotes bad habits and you don't really learn the language.

Comment: I've heard good things about flashdevelop but it's not available on mac as far as I know; TextMate seems like a decent alternative on the mac.

Comment: In terms of the connection between the debugger and the application, I think it exists to some degree as the trace in the code above is reported.  Also, there are some dynamic performance and memory usage statistics that are updating within the debugger.

Comment: DeMonster do claim that their debugger will break program execution as normal: http://demonsterdebugger.com/tour/breakpoints

Comment: Your options are very limited on a mac. I did a little searching there isn't much free software for flash on them. Sell the mac and get a real pc :)

Comment: @The_asMan: complete bullshit you are talking about. On a Mac you have the same options like on PeeeCeeee. They are different though...